# How to use several constants deep down a project?

Tags: matlab, struct, global

My question is easily solvable by creating a struct and using it as globals but as I've ever heard that using globals should be avoided I would like to know elegant alternatives. So the problem is:

Imagine a long list of arrays which are kept constant all the time with these constants being only used in a function which is well deep in the project like imagine the following sequence:
main -> calls a -> calls b -> ... -> calls n which needs the constants..

So I thought:

1. creating a struct in main and set it global (what I am looking for alternatives).
2. creating a struct and passing it as an argument through the different subroutines but they will do nothing in a,b,...,n-1. This increases the list of useless arguments in 99% of the functions which I don't like.
3. creating the constants directly in the nth function but this implies creating these variables 1000 times assuming my function n is called 1000 times in a run which sounds silly as they are constant.

---

Another problem that I have is similar.
I would like to know how to do something like common // from FORTRAN as I might want to share common (changeable) values between a limited number of subroutines (~10%) but they are useless in 90% of the subroutines.

PS: Globals have also the other problem that when the project gets big I may repeat some variable name without knowledge.

Comment: *but this implies creating these variables 1000 times assuming my function n is called 1000 times in a run which sounds silly as they are constant* - It's only silly if the profiler shows it makes a significant difference to the execution time of your code. Otherwise that's probably the simplest and most readable solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compute the values in the inner function and store them in [persistent variables](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/persistent.html).

To share values among a small group of related functions, you could define these functions as sub-functions (within the same m-file). Variables defined in the parent function are visible from the child functions.

--

EDIT:

Look at the example in the linked page:

```
function arrayToXLS(A, xlsfile, x1, x2)
persistent dblArray;

if isempty(dblArray) 
    disp 'Writing spreadsheet file ...'
    xlswrite(xlsfile, A);
end

disp 'Reading array from spreadsheet ...'
dblArray = xlsread(xlsfile, 'Sheet1', [x1 ':' x2])
fprintf('\n');
```

You declare the persistent variable. The first time you call the function, it's an empty array. Thus, your function must check to see if the variable was set using `isempty`, if it hasn't been set, it can compute the value to store in the variable.

Comment: I did not know about persistent variables so if I understood if I have a function like: 

[Values]=define_values(T,P) 
Persistent constsA constsB
constsA=[x x x ; x x x; x x x];
constsB=[y y y;y y y; y y y];
for i=1:3
for j=1:3
Values(i,j)=constsA(i)*T+constsB(j)*P
end
end

The matrixes constsA and constsB will just be created the first time and then kept?

Comment: function[]=Set_Constants()

persistent physics

[physics]=Modules()

for i=1:30
    a(i)=i+physics.kB
end

And if the constant is computed in a function.. will it call modules() in every call of set_constants even tough physics is a persistent variable?

Comment: I've replied to your question inside the answer. It's hard to write code in these comments!

Comment: I think I understood with the example along with the example 2)  of Mendi Barel and this seems to me the most appropriate solution for my case. I have a function which creates the variables. and in the inner function where I needed I assign a struct as persistent and create it by calling the function of constants in the first call. Thanks :)

Comment: Is there any performance difference between using globals and persistent variables?

Comment: @nekomatic I don't know. I don't see why there would be, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three methods:

1) Pass the constant stuct as argument. this is more robust. use short name for the struct, like 'C', this way it will not take too much space in code.

2) The struct C is created inside function with persistent variable:

```
function [ C ] = GetConstants()
    persistent Consts
    if isempty(Consts)
        C = struct;
        %System
        C.MAX_USERS=160;
        Etc;
        C=orderfields(C);
        Consts=C;
    else
        C=Consts;
    end
end
```

3) Use both methods, in the main program use C as argument (ofcourse, load it using C = GetConstant() ). In very deep or very rare accessed function use GetConstants() directly.

4) Dont use globals for this. Constants should be the most fast accessed memory, not the most slowest one.

Comment: In 3) the fact that functions are very deep has the opposite meaning in my case, they are called a huge number of times and that's why I did not want to pass it as an argument from main to 50 functions where it does nothing untill get to call the function where they are used!